# Makefile help (and Shell command)

Tags: parsing, makefile, echo, gnat

I need help extracting test from a shell command for use in a Makefile variable.

Basically, I am using two different versions of a piece a software on different servers, but using a common makefile.  One is the **6.4.2** version of gnatmake, the other is the **6.2.2** version.  The problem is that the **6.2.2** version does not support the **"--unchecked-shared-lib-imports"** flag, which I need to have included when compiling against the **6.4.2** version.

To find the version, I figured I could use the **'gnatmake --version'** command.  This is what each returns, below..  How can I parse out the version?  (6.2.2 or 6.4.2)?

**gnatmake 6.2.2:**

```
GNATMAKE Pro 6.2.2 (20090612-43)
Copyright (C) 1995-2009, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
See your AdaCore support agreement for details of warranty and support.
If you do not have a current support agreement, then there is absolutely
no warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
PURPOSE.
```

**gnatmake 6.4.2:**

```
GNATMAKE Pro 6.4.2 (20110614-45)
Copyright (C) 1995-2010, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
See your AdaCore support agreement for details of warranty and support.
If you do not have a current support agreement, then there is absolutely
no warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
PURPOSE.
```

Here is how I was thinking the makefile would be set up, so if the **GNATMAKE_VERSION** is **6.4.2** then **--unchecked-shared-lib-imports** will be in the **GNAT_FLAG** variable which I can include in future parameters.

```
GNATMAKE_VERSION:=$(shell gnatmake --version)

GNAT_FLAG:= 
#  if not equal (GNATMAKE_VERSION=6.2.2)
#     GNAT_FLAG:= "--unchecked-shared-lib-imports"
# 

test:
    echo "$(GNATMAKE_VERSION)"

test2:
    echo "$(GNAT_FLAG)"
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: That's a pretty simple way. Does it work?

Comment: I dont know how to parse out the Version from this command:  $(shell gnatmake --version) so I can use it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, I didn't understand the problem at first.)

Try this, if you have `sed`:

```
GNATMAKE_VERSION:=$(shell gnatmake --version | sed -e '/GNATMAKE/!d' -e 's/GNATMAKE Pro \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/')
```

or this, if you have `head` and `cut`:

```
GNATMAKE_VERSION:=$(shell gnatmake --version | head -n 1 | cut -f3 -d' ')
```

or this, if Gnatmake allows it:

```
GNATMAKE_VERSION:=$(shell gnatmake --version)
GNATMAKE_VERSION:=$(word 3,$(GNATMAKE_VERSION))
```